# when use this keyword, Why it output different result in debug and run?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

just I don't know why the result is different in `debug mode` and in `run mode` ,can somebody illustrate why it would be like this?

**Purpose: Press a Button, Change tag `id` value**

```js
    var btnInst = document.getElementById("btnObj");
    btnInst.onclick = function func1() {
        console.log(this);
        this.value = "Another";
        this.type = "";
        this.id = "newID";
        console.log(this);
    };
```

```html
<input type="button" value="BUTTON" id="btnObj"><br/>
```

1. in Chrome `debug mode`, when press the button the result is:

`<input type="" value="BUTTON" id="btnObj">`

`<input type="" value="Another" id="newID">`

2. But, in Chrome `running mode`, the result is

`<input type="" value="Another" id="newID">`

`<input type="" value="Another" id="newID">`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by `devug mode` or `running mode` but if you run the code you will see that the first time you click the input it logs your #1 and every click after that it logs your #2 because the input is already changed.

Comment: just try run it in chrome or safari,  and then, debug the  `console.log(this);`  , the output is different

Comment: It works exactly as I explained in my first comment. Push the "Run code snippet" button.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. The SO console is different.

Comment: that's not my question mate, my question is the output is different if you using this snippet running in either chrome or  safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing a difference in the browsers console is because the console displays a "live" version of the `input`. Live means that the console shows changes as they happen to the input, in real time (it's logging a reference). I'll demonstrate.

**Your original code**

```js
    var btnInst = document.getElementById("btnObj");
    btnInst.onclick = function func1() {
        console.log(this);
        this.value = "Another";
        this.type = "";
        this.id = "newID";
        console.log(this);
    };
```

```html
<input type="button" value="BUTTON" id="btnObj"><br/>
```

**Grabbing the properties instead of the reference to the "live" input**

```js
    var btnInst = document.getElementById("btnObj");
    btnInst.onclick = function func1() {
        console.log('value:', this.value, 'type:', this.type, 'id:', this.id);
        this.value = "Another";
        this.type = "";
        this.id = "newID";
        console.log('value:', this.value, 'type:', this.type, 'id:', this.id);
    };
```

```html
<input type="button" value="BUTTON" id="btnObj"><br/>
```